# Piano Learning book with fingering details

Tags: piano, teaching, books

I wish to learn piano by myself. So I am looking for a comprehensive teaching book with lots of shertmusic with fingering details available. Book should cover

1. big collection of music sheets with finger position details ranging from simple to hard difgiculty level.
2. Most of the chords with its finger position
3. Different piano techniques and should cover most scales including pentatonic scale.

Is there any book available? Please advise.

Comment: There are many many books available, however, I feel that following suggested fingerings, as well as trying to read the music *and* find your way round the black and white keys just adds extra complication. That apart, the question will be disallowed, as asking for materials like this are not part of this site's remit.

Comment: @Tim, fingering is an absolutely necessary component of piano playing. Why would playing suggested fingering be an extra complication?

Comment: @HeatherS. - it's another piece of data to cope with. It can become like 'painting by numbers', where student relies more on the numbers than the dots. Part of the learning process is working out personal best fingering - the printed is only 'suggested'.  Sometimes the suggested fingering just doesn't suit particular players' hands. Of course it's an essential part of piano playing, but for me, it's similar to tab for guitarists. It shows only one way to play something.

Comment: @Tim, I agree that a pianist eventually needs to figure out personal best fingering, but that technique is advanced. At the beginner level, a student needs to follow good fingering patterns because it helps develop finger independence and it also teaches good strategies for moving one from one section of the keyboard to the another. Additionally, standard scale fingerings are useful for knowing what to do when one sees a scale embedded within an actual piece, and if one does choose a different fingering, one will know why. That deviation cannot be explained without first knowing the standard.

Comment: @Tim, the only time beginner book fingerings will not suit a player's hands is if the student has some kind of deformity or physical limitation. In that case, I would suggest that a teacher would be be necessary to help the student make adjustments.

Comment: @HeatherS. - I'm sceptical about 'embedded scales'. Yes, they do occur, but not necessarily starting and/or finishing with roots, as scales do. So the fingering for them may or may not be the same as that used for scales themselves. It's also of concern to me that a beginner picks up music without finger numberings, and then is stumped, without that crutch. One of my students has a span of an easy 10th/11th, and finds suggested fingering hinders. Maybe because I suggested initially that it wasn't going to be much help!

Comment: @Tim, I still follow scale fingering patterns *most* of the time when I see those. But if the scale starts on the 2nd note of the scale, I start with the finger that would play the 2nd note. Of course, it does depend on context, so that is not a "rule." Knowing the fingering patterns for regular scales also help one figure out strategies for any possible modes or variations.

Comment: I recommend "Keyboard Proficiency" by Louise Guhl.  It doesn't have tons of repertoire, but it does have some. It is, however, the most comprehensive guide I've found for an adult learning to play piano. Covers everything from hand and finger position to scales to chords to modes to improv, sight reading, and the list goes on!

Comment: @KevinH Thanks... My question was to recommend a book and you are the only one whi actually did recommend a book. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most beginner books will have fingerings for the simple songs and techniques. However, do not expect a fingering listed for every single note. Occasional fingerings are given to get a student started in the right place at the beginning of a piece or section of a piece, and it is assumed that starting with that fingering gets the hand in position to play the rest of that section. You will need to figure out the remainder.

What you are asking for: basic songs, fingerings, and all scales and chords, is not going to be found all in one place. You can find beginner books to help you read music and play basic songs. You will need to buy a separate book for scales and chords. There are several that will cover all the major and minor scales and chords, but pentatonic and other less common scales may not be included. At that point, you should know enough fingering to figure that out by yourself. The same is true for chords. If you have learned the fingering for your major and minor chords, you should be able to deduce the fingerings for all the others provided you know the theory.